# Yup validation is not working for nested objects for date keys if we have same name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have used the YUP validation. I need to add validation of startDate and endDate from parent under milestones.

```js
export const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape(
  {
    name: requiredString,
    startDate: Yup.date()
      .nullable()
      .when('endDate', {
        is: (val) => val,
        then: Yup.date().nullable().max(Yup.ref('endDate'), 'message'),
      }),
    endDate: Yup.date()
      .nullable()
      .when('startDate', {
        is: (val) => val,
        then: Yup.date().nullable().min(Yup.ref('startDate'), 'message'),
      }),
    milestones: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object().shape(
        {
          name: requiredString,
          startDate: Yup.date()
            .nullable()
            .when('endDate', {
              is: (val) => val,
              then: Yup.date().nullable().max(Yup.ref('endDate'), 'message'),
            }),
          endDate: Yup.date()
            .nullable()
            .when('startDate', {
              is: (val) => val,
              then: Yup.date().nullable().min(Yup.ref('startDate'), 'message'),
            }),
        },
        [['startDate', 'endDate']]
      )
    ),
  },
  [['startDate', 'endDate']]
);
```